# Rails 4 destroy action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling about an annoying issue of my new cmd: method destroy is not working. Everything looks ok, here is the log:

```
Started DELETE "/admin/videos/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-19 19:02:53 +0100
Processing by Admin::VideosController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"yIFTvqxF+ablO8xakneLmlUBLyewaH2syX2Q6QE+9rQ=", "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/admin/videos
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

And my link is:

```
= link_to admin_video_path(video), method: :delete, title: "Delete" do
  %i.fa.fa-trash-o
  Canc
```

After the query the record is still present!

Comment: What does the destroy action in the controller look like?

Comment: Yeah, the controller would be nice to see, are you actually calling destroy in your controller? The SQL in the log just appears to be selecting the record but not doing anything with it.

Comment: Omg I lose video.destroy somewhere!!!! Sorry for the stupid question. I lose 2 hour looking in model and view! I'm trying to add ajax destroy and i leave the row commented! Sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

This is the example code of how the destroy method should look like (inside controller):

```
def destroy
    modelnamehere.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "modelnamehere deleted."
    redirect_to modelnamehere_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you don't have a `before_destroy` callback that is not returning anything other than `true`. Even inadvertently returning `nil` will prevent stop the `destroy` method from successfully executing as it stops the method chain.

**tl;dr** ensure any `before_destroy` callback always return `true` for any success cases.